# How do multiple levels of inheritance affect virtual function call overhead in C++?

Tags: c++, functions, polymorphism

I am considering using a class hierarchy with more than a single level of inheritance, where virtual member functions form a "chain", for example:

```
struct Base
{ virtual void foo(); };

struct D1 : Base
{ virtual void foo(); };

struct D2 : D1
{ void foo(); };
```

However I would like to know before using similar code in practice if this would cause additional dynamic dispatch overhead when calling trough a base class pointer. Consider the following example:

```
D2 instance;
D1* d1ptr = &instance;
Base* baseptr = &instance;

//normal function call to "D2::foo()", no dynamic dispatch.
instance.foo();
//virtual function call to "D2::foo()", one dynamic dispatch.
d1ptr.foo(); 
//virtual function call to "D2::foo()", does this incur additional
//..overhead compared to "d1ptr.foo()"?
baseptr.foo();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, the depth of the inheritance tree does not affect performance. The reason is simple, every instance has its pointer to some [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vtable) (containing function pointers), and a virtual function call goes just thru that vtable.

In other words, your code works like the following C code:

```
struct vtable {
   void (*fooptr) (struct D1*);
};

struct D1 {
   const struct vtable*vptr;
};

struct D2 {
   const struct vtable*vptr;
};
```

And e.g. `baseptr->foo()` is "transformed" at compilation time to `baseptr->vptr.fooptr(baseptr)` (and of course `d1ptr->foo()` is "transformed" to `d1ptr->vptr.fooptr(d1ptr)` etc...)

So the execution cost is the same: get the vtable, and call *indirectly* the function pointer inside. The cost remains the same even if you had a `struct D4` subclass of `struct D3` subclass of `struct D2` subclass of `struct D1`. You could have a `struct D99` with 99 inheritances and the execution cost would remain the same.

<sup>On some processors, any *indirect call* may be slower than a *direct* call, e.g. because of [branch predictor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) cost.</sup>

The data of the vtable themselves is built at compilation time (as constant static data).

Things become a bit more complex with [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) and/or [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)

BTW, some C object frameworks (e.g. [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) from Gtk, or several data structures inside the Linux kernel) also provide their vtable (or class data). Pointing to a data structure containing function pointers is quite common (even in C). Read also about [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) and you'll see a relation with "vtables" (both closures and objects are mixing code with data).

Some C++ compilers (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) may provide [devirtualization](http://hubicka.blogspot.ca/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html) as an optimization technique.

Comment: C++ 11 provides keyword final, does it not, which would make devirtualization of leaf functions straightforward. I have seen gcc devirtualize without final, playing around on the godbolt page, but it's almost hilariously fragile and cannot be relied on.

Comment: @NirFriedman Why would `final` affect the ability of a compiler to determine the static type of a call and thereby devirtualise it? AFAICT it's purely for compile-time checking and cannot possibly affect compiled code, only forestall it. Either way, if a compiler with sufficient optimising savvy and setting can identify the static type - without undue hoop-jumping - then it'll bypass dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @underscore_d `B` inherits from `A`, they both define a virtual function `bar`. A function `foo`, part of a shared library, receives a parameter `B& b`, and calls `b.bar();`. This can be devirtualized only if either `B` or `bar` are marked `final`. But if they are, then devirtualization is trivial and most modern compilers will perform it.

Comment: @NirFriedman Makes sense and seems relevant for library functions, where taking a polymorphic reference/pointer means you can never know for sure what you're being passed. I guess I was thinking in narrower terms about self-contained programs, in which - by my imagination, at least! - the compiler, having visible declarations of the base and all derived classes, can deduce without `final` that the last (here `B`) is never overridden. Emphasis on "can", as I guess whether it _does_ is another question. Regardless, semantically, of course one should mark a class as `final` anywhere they mean it.

Comment: @underscore_d Even in self-contained programs, this kind of optimization can only be done by the linker, not the compiler, and scales very poorly with program size. I'm guessing there are also other deep dark corners. I think the bottom line is that you can rarely expect to see this when inlining does not occur. As I said, devirtualization w/o final is extremely fragile in my experience. Have you actually seen consistent devirtualization without final, without inlining? It seems like your discussion is more theoretical.

Comment: @NirFriedman Yup, it's not something I've profiled yet, so I was just looking for rationales and evidence - or at least anecdotes - supporting it. So I guess I'll take your word for it! If good practices like using `final` lead to any concrete improvements in generated code, then that's a double win.

Comment: @NirFriedman Btw, good catch: When I talked about "the compiler" being able to determine whether a base class was ever overridden, I was really thinking about projects compiled with LTO, as for anything with >1 TU, the linker would need to perform such analysis (if it can/does). LTO has spoilt me; I tend to forget about the underlying separate-compilation model ;-)

Comment: @NirFriedman Here's a good little demo of the ability of `final` to facilitate optimisations as you said - http://msinilo.pl/blog/?p=1329 - at least for GCC and Clang, dunno about The Other Compiler, but it didn't take advantage of this at the time that was written, _quelle surprise_